# Sublime text 4 curly bracket indentation problem

Tags: auto-indent, sublimetext4

Sublime text 4 is giving weird indentation when pressing enter between curly braces

```
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
                          }
```

In some already opened file it is working fine by indenting like this :

```
   for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
   }
```

I tried disabling packages and re enabling them but no success, can someone please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Similar problem in python with simple braces. Did you find the soulution?